How do valuation multiples relate to growth or other company features?
tldr; What's the criteria to choose the multiplier quantity for valuation multiples?
Context:
I am learning to value stocks but I can't find anywhere how to choose the multiplier (the amount next to the x) for a given valuation multiple. And also what company attributes or features influence it.
Are there benchmarks? Of course there are industry/sector averages. But even looking at those, ranges are very wide. For instance the PE multiple in tech stocks.
So I'm looking for guide/documentation to be able to say: "this company should trade in this range for this multiple" where range is something like 8-10 and not like 20-40. Makes sense?
P.S.
I found the article beneath which describes it but
https://firstpagesage.com/seo-blog/ebitda-multiples-by-industry/
Apart from industry and EBITDA range, real-world valuations depend principally on 8 factors:

Recurring revenue
Revenue growth over last 12 months
Key employee turnover
Profit margin
Competitive advantages
Customer concentration
Strength of management team
Growth opportunities


This is just way too large of a topic to be well suited to this site. "How do I value a company" is like... all of finance.

There is no easy answer to your question but I think the key factor is
how fast can it grow earnings in the long run. When it comes to earnings,
there is earnings per share and earnings for the  corporation. Both numbers are relevant but I consider earnings per share the more important one. Related to that, is how fast can the company grow revenue. In the long run, a company cannot grow revenue at 6% and have 12% earnings growth. Also, as a  company gets bigger, it tends to have less earnings growth. You also want to consider revenue per share. That is, if a company is increasing its revenue by 20% a year but its  revenue per share remains unchanged, that would be a red flag for me.
One thing that you did not mention is the balance sheet. Does the company have a lot of debt? If it does, then it maybe hard for it to invest in the future.
You need to consider how will the company due in a recession. Companies that produce cars often do badly in a recession. As such, they will trade at a lower multiples then if they did not have this problem.
You mentioned key employee turnover. As a potential investor in a company, I would ignore this one with the exception of the CEO. The reason I say that is it is hard to know who the key employees are
and if they are doing a good job. Instead, I would focus on the results.

And if you don't know how to determine these facts, join the club. Trying to invest in single companies requires a lot of effort to research them, or a blind faith that the ones you like will do well. Which is one of the reasons we keep suggesting low fee index funds; they are inherently diversified.

Thanks a lot for your answer. Related to my question, I think the formula "The Tao of corporate finance" (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cGOD9qwjoCk) answers it. It relates growth and WACC to the EV.

@LeonardoLanchas If you like my answer, could you accept it? Thanks.
